# Superfish Child Drop Downs Falling Off Page

Tags: javascript, css, superfish

Superfish is a very common menu plugin, so I'm surprised I'm having difficutly rectifying this.

I have a pretty intense menu structure that involves several child menus.  So much so, that a lot of them fall off of the page or out of the browser's view when their parent is hovered.

People have suggested applying a `right: 0px;` property in place of the `left: 0px;` property in the `superfish.css` file, but it looks like the JS script is writing it's own CSS properties to the element as in-line styles. In fact, it actually looks like it's measuring the width of the parent menu in order to apply the correct `left:` value.

The sub-menu's end up looking like this

```
<ul class="sub-menu" style="left: 16.18181818181818em; 
    float: none; width: 14.5em; display: block; visibility: visible;">
```

So, I guess what I'm getting at is... what applies these CSS properties if not the CSS file?  Even when I apply a specific class for menus I want to 'drop-down' to the right instead of the left, the property gets overridden anyway.

Is there a way to rectify this, or just make it so once I get to the second level of drop downs (when drop downs start going to the left instead of below) they go to the right instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was just dealing with the same issue. It looks like this "feature" fell off the road map :)

Anyways I found this [Superfish Menu text off-screen](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/suprtfish-menu-text-off-screen)

it solved it for me but YMMV as always.

Answer (score 1):

if CSS comes from Javascript,

then you may use `!important` in your style sheet to over ride it.

Add a comment aside your rule in style sheet , so one may remenber or understand the use of
 `left:0!important;/* !important  is here to overide style from  js' suckerfish menu */` :)

Answer (score -1):

I've solved this issue just doing this...

jQuery Superfish Menu Plugin - v1.7.4

just open Superfish.js and find the `visibility` change to `display`

example:

`visibility: hidden` to `display : none`

`visibility: visible` to `display : block`

superfish js edit file

[image]

Comment: Please consider adding code as text instead of snapshot

Comment: i cant send this file but i can give you my packeges link
http://a2zdigitalmarketing.com/js/plugins.min.js
find this :  * jQuery Superfish Menu Plugin - v1.7.4